# When implementing the DAO pattern in Java, how should the TransferObjects be implemented and used?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao, data-transfer-objects

I am implementing a DAO pattern as specified in the [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html). In my project, I have 3 modules: `core layer`, which uses `DAO-API layer`, that is implemented by my [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) `DAO-MySQL layer`.

I have questions about the design and use of `TransferObject`s:

**1a)** Is it normal to have `TransferObject`s very redundant as compared to their equivalent "business layer" classes, or the "business layer" classes *are* the `TransferObject`s?

For instance, if in my `core layer` I have a class:

```
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String lname;
    ...
    //various methods here, plus getters/setters
}
```

In `DAO-API layer`, I will have:

```
public class CustomerTO implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String lname;
    ....
    //getters/setters here
}
```

I hate this redundancy between `Customer` and `CustomerTO`. Besides, in the "Example 9.5 Customer Transfer Object" of [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html), it seems to be only one `Customer` class, that *is* the `TransferObject`.

I also see the benefit that having two classes allows my `DAO-API layer` to be completely independent from the `core layer`, and to be provided as a separate module, that end-users won't even know about.

=> **1b)** But maybe my `DAO-API layer` should be part of my `core layer`, and `Customer` *be* the `TransferObject`?

=> **1c)** Or is there something I miss to avoid the redundancy between a core business layer class and its transfer object?

**2)** Is it legit to **not** use `TransferObject`s as parameters when calling DAOs methods? For instance:

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
    public Collection<CustomerTO> getCustomersByNameAndCity(String name, String city);
}
```

Or should I always use something like:

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
    public Collection<CustomerTO> getCustomersByNameAndCity(CustomerTO to);
}
```

What are the drawbacks in using the first method?

Answer (score 0):

1a) Is it normal to have TransferObject
Yes it is normal in scenarios where you are not trying to limit information in the DTO to be sent across.A Data Transfer Object is an object that is used to encapsulate data, and send it from one subsystem of an application to another.

1b) But maybe my DAO-API layer should be part of my core layer, and Customer be the TransferObject?
No, DAO layer is to hide/encapsulate the underlying details of the data in the database. DAOs are used by other sub-systems to get the data from the datasource irrespective the way how it is stored/fetched. DAOs main purpose is to provide simple APIs to do CRUD on data.

1c) Or is there something I miss to avoid the redundancy between a core business layer class and its transfer object?
If your DTOs are not limiting any information then you can use the same class from business layer. But it may cause problems in future enhancements when you have to limit the info.

2) Is it legit to not use TransferObjects as parameters when calling DAOs methods? For instance
No one can stop you doing that. But sometimes DTOs attributes and DAOs attributes may not be easily translated to each other. So you will have to add extra logic for it. This should be taken care by the man in middle, your business layer.

Comment: "If your DTOs are not limiting any information then you can use the same class from business layer. But it may cause problems in future enhancements when you have to limit the info." => in what situations would I want DTOs to limit some information? I don't see any use case. Also, what is the most common solution adopted, to "duplicate" DTOs, or to use directly the business layer class?